# django create N number of forms in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I was wondering if it was possible to write a more generic form to use as a template so that during the render it will create as many forms as necessary? If not how would one write code to create N number of forms, where the number is Dependant on the result of some query set, and also the options in a many to many field are also dependant on a quesry set? I know the code below doesn't work I am leaving it in as more sudo code
forms.py:

```
class OptionalSFRForm(forms.Form):
    selected_optional_sfr = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=sfrs_models.ProtectionProfile.objects.all())
    def Custom(QueryPP):
        selected_optional_sfr = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=QueryPP.Optional_SFR.objects.all())
```

models.py

```
class ST_Title(models.Model):
    Selected_SFR =  models.ManyToManyField(sfrs_models.SFR, related_name='Selected_SFR')
    AttachedPPs = models.ManyToManyField(sfrs_models.ProtectionProfile, related_name='ST_PPs')
```

sfrs.models.py

```
class ProtectionProfile(models.Model):
    Optional_SFR = models.ManyToManyField(SFR, related_name='Optional')
```

template:

```
{% for AttachedPPs in ST_Title.AttachedPPs.all %}
 <form action="{% url 'SecurityTarget:stview' ST_Title.id %}" method="post" id="conformanceform">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{OPTSFRS.Custom(AttachedPPs)}}
</form>
```

Comment: This is what formsets are for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It doesn't look like formsets allows you to secify a parameter used in a query set in the template though? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms

Comment: So this isn't even possible if you write your own custom template filters and try to edit the forms during the template render. There is literally no way to accomplish this. I am really disappointed. I just have to write a manual html in templates instead of using the form class

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and why you think it's not possible with formsets. You can easily control the number of forms in a formset.

Comment: but you can't set anything in the template? I can't even figure out how to set the queryset in teh views.py for each iteration of the formset?